# Is it necessary that Data Source of connection string must match the system name

Tags: vb.net

This is my first post to this precious website. I am a new learner of vb.net. I am working on a simple purchase project, where i got some errors. But the first thing is which baffled me is:

This is my connection string at module level, on the developed machine.

```
    Public strCn As String = "Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = PSys; Integrated Security = false; User ID = sa; Password = 123;"
```

Is it mandatory that Data Source must be the original name of the System Name. I mean If i use (local) or using ( . ), so will it work or not? Because when i copy my project to any other system for further development so every time i need to change the Data source, otherwise i get the error that: **"Network-related or instance-specific error occurred......."**

Kindly guide me that what i need to do.

Comment: The data source must point to the machine that is hosting your database.

Comment: You should also develop under user credentials that are limited, like users will be when they use your app. You're running under the sa user, which is definitely not the context your users will use.

Comment: @sasfrog, You mean that when i will make the setup file of the project for customer, so during that time, i will change the connection string from (local) to the machine name of the client computer? Is it true?

Comment: It depends on your architecture. Where will the database be hosted for clients? Will your app have a database installed on their local machine?

Comment: The DB will be installed also on the client machine along with app.

Comment: Right, then it should work with localhost, unless the db has been installed as a named instance, in which case you'll need to include the name of the instance as well.

Comment: Ohh. the machine on which the application is developed has Default instance of SQL, while the system (computer/PC) in my office having SQL Server with Named Instance. Sow what i need to do now?

Comment: Good resource - [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Answer (score 1):

When you are developing an application which uses a database server such as MsSQL it is not wise to install the server along with your application in every pc which is installed to. For example what are you going to do if a customer has a local network with 10 computers? Are you going to install SQL server in all 10 of them? And if so what if they need to share data?

So your best approach (based on common practice by other applications) will be to allow the user to install the SQL server where he wants and let him configure your application and point it to the server's location. If you follow that path then the configuration of your application can be in the setup application or in the application itself.

Now about the development phase, I had a similar situation in which I needed to develop the same application in two different computers. What I did was to install the SQL server in both of them with a named instance "sqlexpress" then in the application I used the

> Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder

class to build the connection string. I did something like this:

```
Public Function getDevConnectionString() As String
    Dim csb As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(My.Settings.dbConnectionString) '<-My original cs in app settings

    csb.DataSource = My.Computer.Name & "\sqlexpress"

    Return csb.ConnectionString
End Function
```

Whenever I need a connection string I simply call getDevConnectionString() which returns the connection string based on the computer name plus the sql server instance name. For example:

```
        Dim cs As String
#If DEBUG Then
    cs = getDevConnectionString()
#Else
    cs = getReleaseConnectionString()
#End If
```

where getReleaseConnectionString() is the function that returns your connection string configured by the customer.

Hope this point you the right direction...

Comment: @ Christos, In my situation this time, the client has only one system (stand Alone). He has no network this time, so Do i simply set the Connection string in application itself? Right?

Comment: You can do that but I strongly suggest to implement the method in my answer even if you have only one installation. Furthermore it does solve your problem when developing in two computers. Invest some time into this now and it will save you hours of struggling later...

Comment: Okay. Lets make me possible to go with your way, but how do i adjust this code in mine. My connection and all common objects, along with all queries and functions, reside in a separate module, so how do i implement your technique?

Comment: By separate module you mean a dll in which you do not have access to its source code?

Comment: No no. Its simple module with my forms. Not a dll.

Comment: As I understand you want me to write your connection string functions for your module, I am sorry but there is not time for that. However you can try to do it yourself and post new questions whenever you have a problem. My code is intended as a guideline in order to implement a similar approach in your app so it must be easy to adopt it in your module.

Comment: No Christos, You inferred it wrong way. I never wanted or even thought that you write code for me. Actually I'm not a professional programmer, but a Newbie to vb.net, so understanding new codes i.e. class so it would be difficult for me. I will try to do it. :) Thank you very much for your participation.

Comment: Please don't get offended what I mean from my last comment is that you need to start implementing a solution and ask questions during your progress. I am telling you this because it is clear from your comments that you have not some basic knowledge about vb, knowledge that it is impossible to get from the scope of this (one) question. For example my code can be used inside a module as is without any modification at all but you can not see that because you have not yet cleared out basic vb concepts as classes and modules and I cannot provide guides without violating SO rules of answering...

Comment: You mean that i need to work on to solve the problem, and if any problem occurred so i will ask in forum, Right? (for learning I'm looking for book). :)